# Localization: how asp.net page go for userspecific resource file on authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I am working on localization of an asp.net web site.
We have a user specific resource file like:

```
(Folder) de-DE 

1. Default_resource_file 
2. UseridFolder
```

So suppose user **abc** logged in for **de-DE** local, then asp.net would first need to check whether **abc** specific file is present or not. If it is present, then use that file, else go for default file.

Is there any ***automatic*** functionality for this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a GenericPage.cs class to your project, inherit it with System.Web.UI.Page and write the following code there:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Session["Culture"]);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(Session["Culture"]);
        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
```

Now Inherit the required page with GenericPage.cs instead of System.Web.UI.Page and add the following code there:

```
public void SetCulture(string culture)
{
Session["Culture"] = culture;
this.InitializeCulture();
}
```

For more information read [my](http://www.codeproject.com/Members/Ammar4556257) [answer](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/662652/Unable-to-access-resx-file-in-Csharp-code-behind-i#answer4)